# orientation support in ios5

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

I am developing an application with orientation support for both portrait and landscape mode.

I was achieving this by changing view frame and assets size in

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);
}
```

Its working fine in ios4.3 and below.

When i tried to run in Xcode4.2 and ios5.0 simulator orientation is not clear. I mean when changed from portrait to landscape view is not fitting to screen (frame size is less than the actual landscape frame size).

Any idea why its happening?

Many Thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply frame when orientation change actually taken place xcode4.2 and iOS 5 have some fast respons for orientation change and other views and controls are improved so its not working for you so you will try it either in  didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation or willRotateFromInterfaceOrientation it will works fine now.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   //support for all orientation change 
    return YES;
}
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
 // in iOS statusBarOrientation is correct than all other orientation changes  
 if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
  self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);
 else
  self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the orientation support in property setting 
and try with this one

this is with status bar

```
  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,768,1004);
}
else{
   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,748);
}
}
```

Comment: Have designed views using xib. So not writing anything in viewdidLoad.     Its just                                           - (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];                                                      }

Comment: can you upload the screenshots of your simulator in landscape and potrait?.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding... solved that by setting frames in wilrotateToInterface