# Interface rotation work on iOS 6 but non on iOS5

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

My app rotation is working correctly on iPad 3 and iPad 2 with iOS6 but not on iPad1 with iOS5.

I'm using a tab bar controller and 5 view controller. On each view controller i have this code:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
if(self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait||self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    self.view=self.VerticaleAppunti;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FONDO_VERT.jpg"]];
}
if(self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft||self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    self.view=self.OrizzontaleAppunti;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FONDO.jpg"]];
}
```

}

Comment: Next time, please use the search. And have a look at the iOS6 changes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011812-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to implement this method for orientation change in ios 5:

```
    - (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   //support for all orientation change 
    return YES;
}
```

[orientation support in ios5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785186/orientation-support-in-ios5)